# Gettin a syntax error for >>> print (x " is greater than " y)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
x = input()
y = input()
if int(x) > int(y):
    print (x " is greater than " y)
else:
    print (y " is greater than " x)
```

Here I want to put the value of  y and x in the statement

```
>>>  print (y " is greater than " x)
```

But I am getting a `>>> ***SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You need to concatenate x and y inside the print statement with your string `print (x + " is greater than "+  y)` and `print (y + " is greater than " + x)`

Comment: You need the `+` operator to concatenate strings. Just putting a space between them doesn't work, and is, as the error says, invalid syntax.

Comment: you can use  `,` to display many values with one `print()` -  `print(y, "is greater than", x)` - and it will automatically add space between values.

Answer (score 3):

You cant just put variables and a string without connecting them. On option is to use f-string if you are using Python 3.6 or newer

```
if int(x) > int(y):
    print(f'{x} is greater than {y}')
else:
    print(f'{y} is greater than {x}')
```

If you don't use `format`

```
if int(x) > int(y):
    print('{} is greater than {}'.format(x, y))
else:
    print('{} is greater than {}'.format(y, x))
```

Or concatenate with `+`

```
if int(x) > int(y):
    print(x + ' is greater than ' + y)
else:
    print(y + ' is greater than ' + x)
```

Comment: Show the `+` too, that is what is wrong with the original.

Comment: Suggesting completely different approaches, but not fixing the original.

Comment: I still don't like the order of them, but let it be.